# Which one is the folder containing iPhone/iPad images

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing an application and I'd like to list the images present in the "Documents" directory of my application (to load images using iTunes) and I'd like to list the images and photos taken by the Camera as well.

And I do know about **UIImagePickerController**, but I don't need that. I want to integrate the photos and the loaded application images in the same place. But I can't find any information about where can I find all the device camera photos.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the photos stored in the photo library using the Assets Library Framework. Check out the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html

Specifically, you want to use ALAssetsLibrary's `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` to enumerate the `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos` type, and enumerate the photos in that group with ALAssetGroup's `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:`.

Some links with sample code:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/

http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/